# Sed pattern to exclude values

Tags: sed, temperature

I have file with temperature values:

```
$ cat temperature.txt
[1450746005000,18.00],[1450746365000,18.00],[1450746725000,17.94],[1450747085000,17.94],[1450747445000,17.94],[1450747805000,17.94],[1450748165000,17.94],[1450748525000,17.88],[1450748885000,17.88],[1450749245000,17.88],[1450749606000,17.88],
```

Sometimes my station saves wrong values like: (a second value)

```
[1453634645000,19.06],[1453635364000,[1453658405000,19.13],
```

I would like to remove only wrong value and overwrite this file.
In this case its [1453635364000,

I found out how to search for "good" values. But I don't have any idea how to remove wrong ones.

```
sed 's/\[[^]]*,?\],*//g' temperature.txt > temperature.txt.proper
rm temperature.txt && mv temperature.txt.proper temperature.txt
```

Comment: How inventive is the wrong formatting?  Just a timestamp without the temperature and close square bracket, or can the device get more inventive?  It is likely that your best bet is to find only the good values, and for that I'd probably use Perl though Python could also do the job.  For example, `perl -lne 'while (m/(\[\d+,\d+\.\d+])/g) { print $1 }' data` prints the valid readings one per line; and `perl -ne 'while (m/(\[\d+,\d+\.\d+])/g) { print "$1," } } END { print "\n"' data` prints them all on one line (assuming the data file is called `data`).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sed 's/[[0-9]\+,\[/[/g;s/[[0-9]\+,$//g' file
```

To edit your file "in place" add sed's option `-i`.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;s/\[[0-9]+,($|\[)/\1/;ta' file
```

This removes numbers followed by a `,` followed by a `[`. When two or more of this kind of pattern are adjacent global substitution is insufficient and the pattern matching must begin again hence the loop.